# I have a datatable includes one column of Guids, I want to conver it to list of Guid, what should I do?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 DataTable calculationList = new PayrollCalculations().GetCalculaitonByPayrollCalculationCommandGuid(payrollCommandGuid);
```

this includes a column with 10 Guids.

```
 List<Guid> commandGuid = calculationList.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

it does'nt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List<Guid> commandGuid = calculationList
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dataRow => dataRow["GuidColumnName"])
    .Cast<Guid>()
    .ToList();
```